# torsion element of group associated to formal group

Tags: group-theory, formal-power-series, ramification, formal-groups

Let $R$ be complete local ring
$M$ be the maximal ideal of $R$

$F$ be a formal group defined over $R$, with group law $F（X,Y）$.

According Silverman's book 'the arithmetic of elliptic curves', example 6.1.1,

> If $R$ is integers in any field unramified extension of $\Bbb
>  Q_p$,then group associated to formal group $F$,$F（M）$ has no torsion.

But there are no proof or reference. I searched a lot, but I couldn't find article regarding this problem.

How to prove this?

Reference（pdf,book） is also appreciated, thank you for your help.

Comment: I think he explained there that $F(M)$ is indeed isomorphic to the additive group $M$, thus has no torsion.

Comment: That does not hold in general. If R is integer ring of ramified extension of Qp, there are torsion elements.